# Question regarding creating reference wikis

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I recently created two community wikis in an attempt to provide a good reference for everyone. Some people are now trying to close them (+ downvoting, but that's not the issue) because of the `NARQ` policy. Despite the fact that many people find (and might find) them very useful.

So, the first question is: Does the fact that this ain't a question weigh more than the fact that many people find it useful?

Some people claim it should be added to the tag wikis but I disagree. Technology changes fast, especially with HTML5-related stuff. While only allowing people with 2000 rep to edit the tag wiki (+ being in top 20 / own bronze badge), the change is too big it gets outdated.

So, what do you think? If this kind of wikis is not allowed on SO,  I will delete the posts (it's not my intention to break any rules).

These are my wikis (edit: I've changed them so they are questions now):

- [what are good resources for learning html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272463/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html5)
- [what are good resources for learning html5 websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets)

The following community wiki is the same deal, but why is this one allowed and mine are not?

- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: do the new tag wiki arrangements work better for you? that is, they are based on suggested, peer-reviewed edits by any registered user until you get to 20k?

Answer (score 4):

Your posts are useful, but better suited for Tag Wikis. I believe you knew that, but you don't like the reputation requirements. You may have cause to argue *that* issue but that **does not give you just cause to circumvent the system** requirements and inappropriately use the site in a way that is not intended. That's why your questions should be closed.

I'm sure your intentions are well-meaning, but you should have known you weren't using the system properly when you had to post your…

> > > ## Placeholder to suppress question from listing.

…another system behavior you found necessary to finagle your way around. It's not appropriate to simply side-step rules, requirements, and behaviors when they don't work the way you wish.

This is a Q&A site… "Questions" and "Answers." You said it yourself that your post is NOT a question, but an attempt to create a useful community wiki. If the system does not work to your liking, bring it up in meta and suggest changes. That's what meta is for.

Comment: I've changed it into questions, and deleted the placeholders. Is that ok or should I just delete all content from SO?

Comment: @Enrico It still isn't a question; it's a blog post that leads with a question. Your question shouldn't contain its own answer, that's not how SO works.

Comment: `it's a blog post that leads with a question` not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the fact that this ain't a question weigh
>   more than the fact that many people
>   find it useful?

@Enrico Pallazzo I also had the same concern that its more important and it made me feel bad  (and also re-opened questions, rebelled and the whole nine yards) but I think I am somewhat starting to get it now. A question must be question & [simple & to the point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70901/getting-back-in-touch-with-the-so-community-hot-to/70903#70903).

I think it's also not bad to understand who we really are here (in theory but most importantly in practice as well) ... we are: just variables and StackOverflow is our function. And you know what happens when a variable does not play by the rules ... buffer overrun (ops, GOds of SO -- who said that, I meant to say stackoverflow:). So yeah, [scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29) is important even when you don't code I guess:)

**EDIT:** I just read the FAQ of SO and it suggests that you can post more open-ended questions on [this site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), I don't know how the wikis will be accepted there but it may work, try it. I think it may work, I may try it too.