# How to get back in touch with the SO community

Tags: discussion, behavior

Say you have annoyed some (or, possibly, a lot) of people on SO and have landed outside the [circle of trust](http://www.shirtquarters.com/shirts/media/images/circle_1_m.jpg). Can anything (practical) be done to "get back in"? Have you had such experiences and recovered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you ask plain, vanilla, questions, and provide plain, vanilla, answers, no one will remember how much their eyes hurt reading anything from the past. Questions that have straightforward technical answers, answers that solve a real problem.

Comment: This. Really. We try to push the mantra *"judge the content, not the poster"* and to the extent that we manage it you'll be fine. You'll note that we don't have any mechanism for flagging *people*, and this is exactly why.

Comment: |@ dmckee: yeah I think somebody advised me on this, ok sounds ok

Answer (score 0):

Avoid drama, stick to the facts and the code.

And above all, follow these [wise words](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7532GXPnO8).